# How to block execution of same exe file already running?

Tags: qt4

I'm building client/server apllication on QT.
I just want user to execute only one application per a machine.
I've heard MUTEX can be used for those kind of situation.
Does anyone get some tips on MUTEX or anything else?
Thanks.

Comment: The concept of a Mutex could certainly apply to the situation, but you might find using a QMutex not very applicable, or just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try QtSingleApplication: http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsingleapplication - works fairly well.

Comment: QtSingleApplication also let's you send messages to the running instance.

Comment: I added it and i'm trying. Thanks for your help.